# I have to do two proofs. One I have "if G is abelian, then G/H is abelian."

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have to do two proofs.

1) If G is abelian, the the factor group G/H is abelian.

2) If H and K are normal in G, then H intersect K is normal in G.

Comment: What is G/H is normal in?

Comment: I think the OP meant to say G/H is ableian. Just a slip of words.

Comment: @Susan, you've asked 4 questions related to group theory in the last 20 minutes or so. I think it is about time you show some self effort, some ideas, insights, etc. in your own work.

Comment: @Susan I think you should be fine with showing that G/H is abelian as long as you remember the definition of the factor group and what it means for a subset of G to be a coset. Try writing those definitions down and seeing if that helps.

Comment: If you Google for [intersection "normal subgroups"](http://www.google.com/search?q=intersection%20%22normal%20subgroups%22), you'll get a few useful hits for the second question.

Comment: These come straight from the definions Susan.  Just write them out.

Answer (score 2):

1) Hint: Here you just need to know how you compose elements in $G/H$:
$$
(gH)(hH) = (gh)H
$$

2) You want to show that for all $g\in G$, $$g(H\cap K)g^{-1}\subseteq H\cap K.$$

So let $g\in G$. Now $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ and $gKg^{-1} \subseteq K$ because both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$. Since
$$
\begin{align}
H\cap K &\subseteq H \\
H\cap K &\subseteq K
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
g(H\cap K)g^{-1} &\subseteq gHg^{-1} \subseteq H\quad \text{and}\\
g(H\cap K)g^{-1} &\subseteq gKg^{-1} \subseteq K.
\end{align}
$$
So $g(H\cap K)g^{-1}$ is contained in both $H$ and $K$, hence
$$
g(H\cap K)g^{-1} \subseteq H\cap K.
$$